# Visual Studio Make this the default for all deletes?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

When deleting a file I accidentally checked 'make this the default for all deletes'.  Now whenever I rename a file it deletes it in my source control server.  How do I 'uncheck' make this the default?  I already tried Tools --> import export settings --> reset all settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Click the Tools menu and then Options...

In the tree view of that dialog, find Source Control->Environment.

Click the Reset button next to the label that says "If dialogs were hidden using Don't show this again, click Reset to view them again."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of that particular option.  It's possible it's an option specific to your source code control provider plugin.  It would explain why it doesn't get reset whenever you do a DevEnv reset settings.

Try going to the following page and seeing if the option lives there

- Tools
- Options
- Source Control
- Select your plugin and examine the options

What source code control plugin are you using BTW?

Comment: Yeah I looked their too and didn't see anything.  I am using Dynamsoft SCM Anywhere.  I've seen this same option with TFS and Source Safe.  I thought it was a standard option.